# get position of canvas element after drag relative to canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kineticjs

I double click on a canvas to create an element, and the user can do this n times. Each element is draggable.

For each element, if I drag it to within a certain rectangle of x/y coordinates, I want to then `clearRect()` within that rectangle, effectively deleting the dragged element.

How implement this?

Current:

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 662,
    height: 983
});
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

$(stage.getContent()).on('dblclick', function (event) {
    var pos = stage.getMousePosition();
    var mouseX = parseInt(pos.x);
    var mouseY = parseInt(pos.y);
    var text = new Kinetic.Text({
        x: mouseX,
        y: mouseY,
        text: cc,
        fill: "blue",
        draggable: true,
    });
    layer.add(text);
    layer.draw();
}
```

Comment: I don't think `getMousePosition()` is a working function

Answer (score 0):

You can use yourElement.on("dragend",handler) to test if the element is inside the deletion rectangle.

If it is inside you can use yourElement.destroy() to destroy that element.

Example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/jqPhe/

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 350,
    height: 350
});
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
stage.add(layer);


// define the boundaries of the deletion box

var dx=200;
var dy=40;
var dw=100;
var dh=100;


// create the deletion box

var deleteMe=new Kinetic.Rect({
    x:dx,
    y:dy,
    width:dw,
    height:dh,
    stroke:"red"
});
layer.add(deleteMe);
var label=new Kinetic.Text({
    x:dx,
    y:10,
    text:"Drag here to delete\n(Must be fully inside)",
    fill:"black"
});
layer.add(label);


// create a circle element for testing purposes

var circle1 = new Kinetic.Circle({
    x:100,
    y:100,
    radius: 30,
    fill: 'red',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 4,
    draggable: true
});

// on dragend: test if this circle is inside the deletion rectangle.  If yes, delete this circle.

circle1.on("dragend",function(){
    var x=this.getX();
    var y=this.getY();
    if(x>=dx && x<=dx+dw && y>=dy && y<=dy+dh){
        this.destroy();
        layer.draw();
    }
});
layer.add(circle1);
layer.draw();
```